# Numpy array mean function did not exclude masked element in mean computation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new in python programming, please forgive me if my question is too basic. But I am trying to use masked_array to calculate the mean of three arrays to produce a third array without using the elements with values less than zero. Using these steps:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.ma import masked_array

d=[]
a = np.array([[-2,-3,-4,-6],[5,2,6,1],[9,3,2,4],[3,1,1,2]])
b = np.array([[3,4,2,4],[5,2,6,1],[9,3,2,4],[0.3,12,1,3]])
c = np.array([[2,3,4,5],[7,0,1,5],[10,9,2,3],[1.5,2.01,2,0.2]])

mask = (a <= 0).astype(int) 
a = masked_array(a,mask)

d.append(a)
d.append(b)
d.append(c)
result = np.array(d).mean(axis=0)
print result

[[ 1.          1.33333333  0.66666667  1.        ]
[ 5.66666667  1.33333333  4.33333333  2.33333333]
[ 9.33333333  5.          2.          3.66666667]
[ 1.6         5.00333333  1.33333333  1.73333333]]
```

I thought that (from documentation that) if one uses the numpy array mean function on arrays with masked values, that it will not consider them (the masked values) in computing the mean. I expected the result to be

```
[[  2.5          3.5  3.  4.5        ]
 [ 5.66666667  1.33333333  4.33333333  2.33333333]
 [ 9.33333333  5.          2.          3.66666667]
 [ 1.6         5.00333333  1.33333333  1.73333333]]
```

Please, does anyone have some tips on how I can use the numpy.ma.masked_array to archive this?

Comment: This isn't part of the problem, but you could write `d = [a,b,c]` instead of appending.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `np.array(d)` does not create a masked array.  The mask in `a` is lost when the arrays in the list `d` are assembled into a bigger (nonmasked) array.

One way to fix it is to replace this:

```
result = np.array(d).mean(axis=0)
```

with

```
result = masked_array(d).mean(axis=0)
```

E.g.:

```
In [27]: result = masked_array(d).mean(axis=0)

In [28]: result
Out[28]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[2.5 3.5 3.0 4.5]
 [5.666666666666667 1.3333333333333333 4.333333333333333 2.3333333333333335]
 [9.333333333333334 5.0 2.0 3.6666666666666665]
 [1.5999999999999999 5.003333333333333 1.3333333333333333
  1.7333333333333334]],
             mask =
 [[False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Comment: Thank your very much @Warren Weckesser. This work perfectly for this scenario.